# how to wrap text using a computed field for a column powerbuilder 7.0

Tags: powerbuilder

[image]
I want that specific line wrapped to display the full details, any help?

I've tried expressions like rowheight().getrow(),string() and etc and none of them works, sorry im still a programming noob, not really sure what i'm really doing, and the results are not what i expected either. expected result is to get that 1 line to show fully, but the problem is that its a single word, the autosize height in the computed field properties position doesn't work. i don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to consider.  If this is a grid datawindow you can use the Autosize width property of the column (assuming you are using a recent version of PB). Since you are using a **twenty-five year old version of PB** you won't have that option so you will need to 'best guess' the size of the field.  If something other than a grid datawindow you can design the form with a multiline edit control and put the text from the datawindow column into that control which will handle the formatting.  However, if the string has no spaces or cr/lf in it then the control will not wrap it since it has no reference to go by to determine where to break the string up.

Comment: sorry that i didn't explain it more properly, ya it's a grid datawindow but the version i'm using is really old, there's only autosize height available, is there no other way to modify it to text wrap? my task requires it to be within the column wihout adjusting other columns' height/width.